# Express roots of quadratic equation in a specific form

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

By solving this equation, I got two roots as follows:

```
Solve[1 + Subscript[a, 1]*s + Subscript[a, 2]*s^2 == 0, s]
```

[image]

Is there a way to express it in the form below in *Mathematica*?
To make it clear, with "form" I mean to say the way parameters are grouped as below. Also, I don't need to replace rule by equal or square bracket as below.
Thank you all for the help. I thought there is a simple solution to this but it seems that I am too demanding.

[image]

Comment: You want a solution in TeX?

Comment: Hi,it can be in anything but should be grouped at the form above.

Comment: Why you mean by "the form"? Equal sign? Or what?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. With "form" I mean how the parameters are grouped, not sign or something else. Just the way how it is grouped.

Comment: Would typing it out explicitly work?  It's probably faster than figuring out how to code it.  *Mathematica* is much better at computing than at putting expressions into elegant forms for typesetting.

Comment: Yes, it works but I am curious if there is a way to do that.

Comment: One obstruction is the ordered pair returned by `Solve` is not equivalent to the ordered pair $(s_1, s_2)$ that you desire.  The correspondence depends on the sign of $a_1$, so one might have to transform the equation, instead of working on the solutions returned...Hmm, sort of thinking out loud...

Comment: Have a look at `Solve[c + s + a s^2 c == 0, s] /. c -> 1/c`…

Comment: You can't ever get valid *Mathematica* output containing square brackets as in your example. So the answer is **no**, this can't be done in the specific form you want.

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry I didn't make it clear that the result don't need to be replaced by the equal sign or use square bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce a function:

```
f[expr_, x_] := HoldForm[x]*Expand[expr/x];
```

The quadratic equation of yours is:

```
ss = Solve[1 + Subscript[a, 1]*s + Subscript[a, 2]*s^2 == 0, s]
```

Its solutions are:

```
   ss[[1, 1, 2]]
```

and

```
ss[[2, 1, 2]]
```

Check it yourself, otherwise its appearance here is too cumbersome.

Now application of the above function to these two solutions:

```
    f[ss[[1, 1, 2]], -Subscript[a, 1]/(2 Subscript[a, 2])]

 f[ss[[2, 1, 2]], -Subscript[a, 1]/(2 Subscript[a, 2])]
```

returns what you need.

Have fun!

Comment: I think you have to do something with the equation like I did or J.M. does in [his comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109253/express-roots-of-quadratic-equation-in-a-specific-form#comment295752_109253).  For instance, your formatting function `f` with the solution in my answer (omitting `Rule -> Equal`) gives exactly what the OP seeks. +1

Comment: @Michael E2 In fact the function I introduced is like the function FactorOut from the Presentations of David Park. I would recommend to use the package Presentation best of all, but as soon as not everybody has it...

Answer (score 2):

The underlying form of the desired output is a product (`Times`) of three factors.  I don't know how much one can change its typesetting, since much of it is automatic.  This gets us to the desired forms:

```
eqn = 1 + Subscript[a, 1]*s + Subscript[a, 2]*s^2 == 0 /. 
   Subscript[a, 2] -> u Subscript[a, 1]^2 /.
   s -> s/Subscript[a, 1]
Solve[eqn, s] /.
  {s -> sol_} :> {s -> sol/Subscript[a, 1]} /.
  u -> Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1]^2 /.
  Rule -> Equal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]